# Xamarin.Forms UWP app crashes in release mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

My UWP Xamarin.Forms works fine in Debug mode, but crashes in release. This is MenuPage.xaml.g.cs:

[image: What can cause this?]

### Added

I was able to get deeper, please see
[FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel() throws an exception in UWP Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717470/freshpagemodelresolver-resolvepagemodel-throws-an-exception-in-uwp-release)

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: dynamic loading of code / assemblies is not supported in UWP (System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[])). Do you use this?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't think so. Please see my addition to the question.

Comment: use [ExceptionSettings to configure VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown) to stop at the line where it causes the Exception.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Unfortunately, it did not let me go deeper than I already was. Further ComAwareEventInfo.cs is not found.

Comment: @DavidShochet Hi , Which version of Xamarin Forms used in project ? And from shared link , does FreshMvvm is uesd in project ?

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT Yes, FreshMvvm is used. Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.947036

Comment: @DavidShochet Okey , got it . If have solution will share here later.

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT Can't wait to see it. I found some solutions online, i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/#troubleshooting, but it did not help. Maybe I applied it incorrectly, but for now I am stick.

Comment: I meant, "I am stUck".

Comment: @DavidShochet I understand, however it maybe related to `FreshMvvm` . Because not used it in my project , so now have no good idea about this problem,

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It could have something to do with your linker options - for Release "Link Framework SDK's only" is often selected, while "Don't link" is selected for Debug.

Try setting "Don't link" for your Release config and see if that is the issue - if yes, you need to figure out what is being linked which it shouldn't, and include it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Pardon my ignorance, but where is that release config for UWP project?

Comment: If I set UseDotNetNativeToolchain to false (like in Debug), it does not crash.

Comment: Not doing much UWP atm. but you should be able to go to options of the project, under build, there should be either a tab or a field with your Linker information?

Comment: It seems like it is only for Android and iOS.