# FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel() throws an exception in UWP Release

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, freshmvvm

My app uses FreshMVVM. This code works for iOS and Android, and for UWP in Debug mode. But UWP release gives an exception here:

```
    private void SetupSimpleNav()
    {
        Page page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MenuPageModel>();
```

The message is:

> Resolve failed: MenuPage - Reason: Operation is not supported on this platform.

Comment: Add stack trace and exception details?

Comment: @FreakyAli his [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58712258/1466046) includes the data

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's okay that would not be needed, It seems the API he is trying to use is not available on UWP

Comment: @FreakyAli But it works in debug.

Comment: Release uses [.NET Native which has some restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/net-native/getting-started-with-net-native#Step2)

Comment: @magicandre1981 But I don't see how I can fix my problem.